# How to realize ROI (region of interest ) in EDSDK?

Tags: roi, edsdk

I need to take picture with EDSDK and save to host only ROI of Image. Do I need to use EdsGetImage? How can I realize this? I don't understand how to use EdsGetImage.

Comment: I think you should learn how to use the EDSDK first. There are a few tutorials out there, just search for it. When you know how to do that, you can continue. The SDK simply returns a Stream to the image. And depending if it's a RAW or a Jpeg image you can manipulate it with whatever programming language you use.

Answer (score 0):

EDSDK only provides complete, uncropped image download to Host in either JPG or CR2. You may crop once the original is downloaded and decoded. You might want to use EDSDKs internal `EdsGetImage`, with `EdsRect` and `EdsSize` parameters to do "cropped" retrieval from the image source.